# How can I get the Facebook post comments?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to work with Facebook Graph API to get the comments from the Wordpress posts.

To do so, I'm using [facebook-node-sdk](https://github.com/node-facebook/facebook-node-sdk).

First I get my access_token:

```
fb.api('oauth/access_token', {
  client_id: this.opts.appId,
  client_secret: this.opts.appSecret,
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
}
```

Then, I try to get the post:

```
fb.api(encodeURI('https://www.../posts/the-post-title-url'), 'get', { fields: 'comments' }
```

But, I get:

> (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments) on node type
>   (URL)

If I just try

```
fb.api(encodeURI('https://www.../posts/the-post-title-url'))
```

I just get `id: https://www.../posts/the-post-title-url`, nothing more.

According the [reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/comments/) I should be sending the ID, but I don't know if the URL it is the ID expect by the FB. If no, well what than could that be and how can I get this ID?

For the record, sending `'/' + encodeURI('https://www.../posts/the-post-title-url') + '/comments'` also does not work.

Surely I'm missing something but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You’re in completely the wrong place, because an external URL isn’t a post object to begin with. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1603507626630008

Comment: @misorude, talking to someone who have the knowledge it's another new level. Thanks!